# how to print array elements in nextline on textView in android

Tags: android

hello everyone i have a 2D array. I am printing the elements of this array on a text View. But my all elements are coming in one row.I want line break between elements. my code is given below and my 2D array is:

```
table[][]={{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},{8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1}}

for(i=0;i<8;i++)
for(j=0;j<2;j++)
{
text = new TextView(this);
text.setText(""+table[j][i]);
}
```

and i am getting output like this:

```
{1,8,2,7,3,6,4,5,5,4,6,3,7,2,8,1}
```

but i want output like this:

```
1,8
2,7
3,6
4,5
5,4
6,3
7,2
8,1
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest not to create TextView in the loop.
Just use same view:

```
table[][]={{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},{8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1}}
text = new TextView(this);

for(i=0;i<8;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<2;j++) {
        text.append(""+table[j][i] + "\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add **Escape sequence \n**.

Try this out,

```
table[][]={{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},{8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1}}

text = new TextView(this);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

for(i=0;i<8;i++)
for(j=0;j<2;j++)
{
    sb.append ( "" + table[j][i] + "\n" );
}

text.setText( sb.toString() );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
text = new TextView(this);

for loop {
        text.append(""+table[j][i] + "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will Add New Line after every two Numbers.

```
table[][]={{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},{8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1}}
String str="";
for(i=0;i<8;i++)
{
  for(j=0;j<2;j++)
  {  
    str=str+table[j][i];
  }
  str=str+"\n";
}
text = new TextView(this);
text.setText(Html.fromHtml(str));
```